# How to create struct for passing between nodes using mpi4py

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I'm using mpi4py to parallelize my code. I want to communicate two pieces of data, an integer and a real number, between nodes. I'd also like to use arrays and the capital `Send` and `Recv` functions which are faster. Reading some tutorials, it seems like it should be possible to do, but I can't find any examples. Here's a simple version of what didn't work:

```
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

dt = numpy.dtype('int,float')
if rank == 0:
    recvBuffr = numpy.zeros(1,dt)
    comm.Recv(recvBuffr, source = MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
    print recvBuffr

else:
    result = rank*1.5
    sendBuffr = numpy.zeros(1,dt)
    sendBuffr[0][0] = rank
    sendBuffr[0][1] = result
    comm.Send(sendBuffr, dest=0)
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpitest.py", line 10, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpitest.py", line 18, in <module>
    comm.Send(sendBuffr, dest=0)
    comm.Recv(recvBuffr, source = MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 248, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:78963)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 237, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:78765)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 380, in mpi4py.MPI.message_p2p_recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:26730)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 366, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_p2p.for_recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:26575)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 375, in mpi4py.MPI.message_p2p_send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:26653)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 358, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_p2p.for_send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:26515)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 114, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:23528)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 114, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:23528)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 59, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22718)
KeyError: 'T{l:f0:d:f1:}'
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 59, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:22718)
KeyError: 'T{l:f0:d:f1:}'
```

I'm thinking that this means it's not enough to use a numpy structured array, and I need to use an MPI datatype. I found on the documentation (https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/apiref/mpi4py.MPI.Datatype-class.html) that there's a function `mpi4py.MPI.Datatype.Create_struct`, which looks like it might be what I want, but I don't understand how to use it. The doc string says:

```
Create_struct(...)
    Datatype.Create_struct(type cls, blocklengths, displacements, datatypes)

    Create an datatype from a general set of
    block sizes, displacements and datatypes
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So starting from the beginning:

It's always possible to get things started just using python's tuples, and MPI4PY's very handy pickling operators to do this by just sending a tuple:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from  mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

assert size > 1

if rank == 0:
    result = comm.recv(source = MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag = MPI.ANY_TAG)
    print(result)
elif rank == 1:
    comm.send((1, 3.14), dest = 0)
```

Running gives

```
$ mpirun -np 2 python send_tuple.py
(1, 3.14)
```

But this pickling/unpickling on each end of the message does take some time, so once things are working, it's certainly a possible target for optimization to do this in native MPI by defining a structure type.

For this to work, you have to know the memory lay out of the structure, which in general isn't available to you with (say) a tuple; the upper-case message operators in MPI4PY rely on numpy, which gives guarantees about memory layout.

For something like an array of structures, you can use numpy [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html):

```
>>> a = numpy.zeros(2, dtype=([('int',numpy.int32),('dbl',numpy.float64)]))
>>> a
array([(0, 0.0), (0, 0.0)],
      dtype=[('int', '<i4'), ('dbl', '<f8')])
```

So now we have an array of structures, with the first field being named 'int' and having a 4-byte integer type, and the second being named 'dbl' and having an 8-byte floating point type.

Once you have this, you can start querying the data layout - finding the size of an individual structure:

```
>>> print(a.nbytes/2)
12
>>> print(a.dtype.fields)
mappingproxy({'dbl': (dtype('float64'), 4), 'int': (dtype('int32'), 0)})
```

That first tells you the extent of the type - the number of bytes between the start of the first element and the start of the second - and the second gives you the offsets in bytes for each element.  That you need for the structure:

```
>>> displacements = [a.dtype.fields[field][1] for field in ['int','dbl']]
>>> print(displacements)
[0, 4]
```

Now you can start creating the MPI data type for the structure and using it just the same way you would with `MPI.INT` or the like.  The only remaining trick is that in the call to Create_struct you have to translate from numpy dtypes to MPI datatypes, but that's fairly straightforward.  The following code gives you a start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from  mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

assert size > 1

def definetype(field_names, field_dtypes):
    num = 2
    dtypes = list(zip(field_names, field_dtypes))
    a = np.zeros(num, dtype=dtypes)

    struct_size = a.nbytes // num
    offsets = [ a.dtype.fields[field][1] for field in field_names ]

    mpitype_dict = {np.int32:MPI.INT, np.float64:MPI.DOUBLE}  #etc
    field_mpitypes = [mpitype_dict[dtype] for dtype in field_dtypes]

    structtype = MPI.Datatype.Create_struct([1]*len(field_names), offsets, field_mpitypes)
    structtype = structtype.Create_resized(0, struct_size)
    structtype.Commit()
    return structtype


if __name__ == "__main__":
    struct_field_names = ['int', 'dbl']
    struct_field_types = [np.int32, np.float64]
    mytype = definetype(struct_field_names, struct_field_types)
    data = np.zeros(1, dtype=(list(zip(struct_field_names, struct_field_types))))

    if rank == 0:
        comm.Recv([data, mytype], source=1, tag=0)
        print(data)
    elif rank == 1:
        data[0]['int'] = 2
        data[0]['dbl'] = 3.14
        comm.Send([data, mytype], dest=0, tag=0)
```

Running gives

```
$ mpirun -np 2 python send_struct.py
[(2, 3.14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If one of the pieces of data being sent is an integer, then sending it as a tag works. (However, since this solution is limited to an integer, I'm still very interested in an alternate answer to my question.)

```
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    result = numpy.zeros(1,float)
    status=MPI.Status()
    comm.Recv(result, source = MPI.ANY_SOURCE, status = status, tag = MPI.ANY_TAG)
    print status.Get_tag(), result

else:
    result = numpy.array([rank*1.5,])
    i = 5
    comm.Send(result, dest=0, tag=i)
```